# JS Use a class method at google chart setOnLoadCallback

Tags: javascript, class, methods, callback, google-visualization

I had a working JS code to display some google chart on page. I thought I refactor this into a JS class like this (cleared and minimized the code for the sample):

```
class MyChar {
   show(title) {
      this.title = title;
      google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['bar'] });
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(this._googleChartOnLoadCallback);
   }

    _googleChartOnLoadCallback() {
        console.log("_googleChartOnLoadCallback is called", this.title);
       // do stuff needed here
    }
}
```

I want to call this like this:

```
var myChart = new MyChart();
myChart.show("My cool chart");
```

I expected to see on the developer console the title, but got an error pointing to the 1st line of the _googleChartOnLoadCallback method:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this is undefined

The google chart loader is (of the html head):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
```

My question is: can or cannot use a class method on a callback - or am I missing something? If I cannot use a callback - then how to insert (add) chart specific data to the callback func?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution:

```
var f = this._googleChartOnLoadCallback.bind(this);
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(f);
```